# Showing that $A\otimes B$ is semiprime if only if its center is semiprime.

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

I was trying to do the exercise 4.17 in Bresar "Introduction to noncommutative algebra" which states the following

Let $A,B$  be simple unital $F$-algebras. Show that the algebra $A\otimes B$ is semiprime if only if $Z(A\otimes B)$ is semiprime.

Here my attempt:

First I will assume that $Z(A\otimes B)$ is semiprime. It is well know that $Z(A\otimes B)=Z(A)\otimes Z(B)$. Let $I\neq 0$ be a nilpotent ideal of $A\otimes B$ and consider $z=\sum_{i=1}^{d}a_{i}\otimes b_{i}$ a non-zero element in $I$ with $d$ minimal. (This was the hint given in the book.) Since $d$ is minimal, both the sets $\{a_{1},\ldots,a_{d}\}$ and $\{b_{1},\ldots, b_{d}\}$ must be
linearly independent. Otherwise, we could, using the linear dependence of some elements, reduce the expression of $z$ and this contradicts the minimality of $d$. Now, since $A$ is simple, we have  $Aa_{1}A=A$ and therefore there exists $r_{i},s_{i}\in A$ such that $\sum_{j}r_{j}a_{1}s_{j}=1$. In this way, for each $j$ we can multiply $z$ on the left by $(r_{j}\otimes 1)$ and on the right by $(s_{j}\otimes 1)$ to obtain an element in $I$ of the form

$r_{j}a_{1}s_{j}\otimes b_{1}+\ast...$

So, adding these elements we arive at an element in $I$ of the form

$u=1\otimes b_{1}+a_{2}'\otimes b_{2}+\cdots+a_{d}'b_{d}$.

And since $d$ is minimaly, once again $\{a_{2}',\ldots,a_{d}'\}$ must be linearly independent. Now given any $a\in A$ the element

$(a\otimes 1)u-(a\otimes 1)u=\sum_{i=2}^{d}(aa_{i}'-a_{i}'a)\otimes b_{i}$

is in $I$ and by minimality of $d$ it is $0$. Moreover taking into account that $\{b_{1},\ldots,b_{d}\}$ is linearly independent we have

$a_{2}',\ldots,a_{d}'\in Z(A)$.

On the other hand, analogously using the fact that $B$ is simple, from $u$ we can get an element in $I$ of the form

$v=1\otimes 1+a_{2}'\otimes b_{2}'+\cdots+a_{d}'\otimes b_{d}'$

with $\{b_{2}',\ldots,b_{d}'\}$ linearly independent and $b_{2}',\ldots,b_{d}'\in Z(B)$.

Now consider the ideal $L:=Z(A\otimes B)v Z(A\otimes B)$ of $Z(A\otimes B)$. Since $I$ is being assumed to be nilpotent, in particular $v$ is nilpotent. As a consequence, $L$ is nilpotent and since $Z(A\otimes B)$ is semiprime we conclude that $v=0$ and by minimality of $d$ follows that $I=0$,  and that implies that $A\otimes B$ is semiprime.

Conversely, assume that $A\otimes B$ is semiprime and let $a\in Z(A\otimes B)$ such that $a(Z(A\otimes B))a=0$. In particular, $a^{2}=0$ (since $1\otimes 1\in Z(A\otimes B)$). In this way, for each $r\in R$ we have

$ara= (aa)r=a^{2}r=0$

and since $A\otimes B$ is semiprime we must have $a=0$. As a consequence, $Z(A\otimes B)$ is semiprime.

Remark: Here I'm using two characterizations of semiprime rings:   A ring $R$ is semiprime $\Leftrightarrow$ $R$ has not non-zero nilpotent ideals  $\Leftrightarrow$ For each $a\in R$ with $aRa=0$, we must have $a=0$.

I would like to know if my attempted solution is correct. Sorry by my English maybe I made some grammatical mistakes.

Comment: You know that a commutative ring is semiprime iff $0$ is the only nilpotent element, right?  It seems like it would simplify your argument substantially.

Comment: The end of the  proof right? In the sense that, how I have showed that $v\in Z(A\otimes B)$ by your argument $v$ automatically must be $0$, what is a contradiction. Right?

Comment: Well, it makes it very easy to prove $A\otimes B$ semiprime implies $Z(A\otimes B)$ is semiprime: If $Z(A\otimes B)$ has a nonzero nilpotent $x$, then $x(A\otimes B)$ is clearly a nonzero nilpotent ideal of $A\otimes B$.   Thus if $A\otimes B$ is semiprime, so is its center.  You don't need any conditions at all on $A$ or $B$, this works for any two $F$ algebras.